# Combining upload to somewhere and download from somewhere

Tags: grammar, phrases

I want to combine the following sentence in a way, that it won't lose its understandability.

```
Data upload to XXX and data download from XXX are possible.
```

I thought something like following:

```
Data upload/download to/from XXX is possible.
```

Is there a better way to write this sentence, or is it even grammatically correct?

Comment: "Data can be uploaded to and downloaded from XXX"

Comment: Well better than mine so I ll use it ty :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of expressing the sentence.

The first is the long version:

> Data uploaded to X and data downloaded from X.

---

When using a parallel construction, you can't omit a part that would result in an incorrect expansion. So, for instance, neither of these work:

> ✘ Data uploaded and downloaded to X.
>   ✘ Data uploaded and downloaded from X.

Although the second sounds slightly better than the first, because *from* works directly after *downloaded* and *to* doesn't, they both end up with one of the verbs using an incorrect preposition.

---

So, to shorten it, you can't omit either of the prepositions.

Both of these will work:

> Data uploaded to and downloaded from X.
>   Data uploaded and downloaded to and from X.

It's also possible to shorten it even further in one of the following fashions:

> Data transferred to and from X.
>   Data transferred between X and Y.

Which version you choose is up to you.

---

As for the version in the question with the slashes, I would say it's grammatical—but, to me anyway, more visually confusing than any of the reworded versions that don't use slashes.